# Quartz scheduleJob function is not working properly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, quartz-scheduler

I have some scheduled functions in my web application which runs on glassfish.
The functions are scheduled to run each day, each week, each month and each year. But only the daily scheduled function starts. Please take a look at the code:

```
public class SchedulerServlet extends GenericServlet {

    private static Boolean isLoaded = Boolean.FALSE;

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return null;
    }

    private void scheduleCronJob(String ejbName, String methodName, String cronExpr) {
        final String jobName = "quartz job: " + ejbName + "." + methodName;
        System.out.println("SchedulerServlet.scheduleCronJob: ejbName: "+ ejbName +" methodname: "+ methodName +" cronExpr: "+ cronExpr ); //asd
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger(jobName, "Quartz Trigger");
        try {
            cronTrigger.setCronExpression(cronExpr);
            scheduleJob(ejbName, methodName, cronTrigger, "-cron");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("STATE : " + "scheduleCronJob fonksiyonunda hata var.") ;
            Logger.getLogger(SchedulerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void scheduleSimpleJob(String ejbName, String methodName, Date time) {
        System.out.println("SchedulerServlet.scheduleSimpleJob: ejbName: "+ ejbName +" methodname: "+ methodName +" time: "+ time ); //asd
        final String jobName = "quartz job: " + ejbName + "." + methodName;
        SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger(jobName, "Quartz Trigger", time);
        try {
            scheduleJob(ejbName, methodName, simpleTrigger, "-simple");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("STATE : " + "scheduleSimpleJob fonksiyonunda hata var.") ;
            Logger.getLogger(SchedulerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void scheduleJob (String ejbName, String methodName, Trigger trigger, String tail) throws SchedulerException {
        try {
            final String jobName = "quartz job: " + ejbName + "." + methodName + tail;
            JobDetail jd = new JobDetail(jobName , "Quartz Job", GFv3EJBInvokerJob.class);
            jd.getJobDataMap().put("ejb", "java:module/"+ejbName);
            jd.getJobDataMap().put("method", methodName);
            System.out.println("SchedulerServlet.scheduleJob: ejbName: "+ ejbName +" methodname: "+ methodName +" trigger: "+ trigger +" tail: "+tail); //asd
            Scheduler sched = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            sched.scheduleJob(jd, trigger);
            Logger.getLogger(SchedulerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, null, jobName + " is scheduled...");
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println("STATE : " + "scheduleJob fonksiyonunda hata var.") ;
    }
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        if (!isLoaded) {
            super.init(config);
            System.out.println("SchedulerServlet.init: "+config.toString()); //asd
            scheduleCronJob("OFReportTimeoutService", "ofTimeout", "*/15 * * * * ?");//Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Day of month, Month, Day of week, Year

            scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "protectionInformationTimeout", "0 0 */3 * * ?");
            Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
            if (!(now.get(Calendar.HOUR)%3 == 2 && now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > 40)) {
                now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
                scheduleSimpleJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "protectionInformationTimeout", now.getTime());
            }

            scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "dailyTimeout", "0 0 4 * * ?");

            scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "weeklyTimeout", "0 15 4 ? * MON");

            scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "monthlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 * ?");

            scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "yearlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 1 ?");

            isLoaded = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("STATE : " + "synchronized isn't running. isLoaded = TRUE") ;
            System.out.println("STATE : " + "OFReportTimeoutService and protectionInformationTimeout services can't run.") ;
            System.out.println("STATE : " + "synchronized isn't running. ") ;
            Logger.getLogger(SchedulerServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, " isn't scheduled...");
        }
    }
}
```

But the interesting thing is when I change the order of the floowing lines

```
    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "dailyTimeout", "0 0 4 * * ?");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "weeklyTimeout", "0 15 4 ? * MON");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "monthlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 * ?");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "yearlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 1 ?");
```

As this

```
    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "weeklyTimeout", "0 15 4 ? * MON");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "dailyTimeout", "0 0 4 * * ?");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "monthlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 * ?");

    scheduleCronJob("ScheduledReportTimeoutService", "yearlyTimeout", "0 0 4 1 1 ?");
```

All the functions are triggered when the time comes. Does this make any sense. Just changing the two functions' order make the code work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot correct your code but this is what worked for me in my project. I have used Quartz to schedule two different events through a Cron expression that is sent in through web.xml when the server starts up..An example of what I have is below for your reference. Maybe, you can follow on similar lines to correct your code...Hope this helps.

**web.xml entry**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>QuartzServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.xyz.SampleSchedulerServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param><param-name>firstCronExpr</param-name><param-value>7 0/1 * * * ?</param-value></init-param>
      <init-param><param-name>secondCronExpr</param-name><param-value>7 0/20 * * * ?</param-value></init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>   
    </servlet>
```

**Servlet Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;


public class SampleSchedulerServlet extends GenericServlet {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SampleSchedulerServlet.class.getName());

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String FIRST_JOB_NAME   = "First Sample Scheduler Job";
    private static final String FIRST_GROUP_NAME   = "First Sample Scheduler Group";
    private static final String FIRST_TRIGGER_NAME = "First Sample Scheduler Trigger";
    private static final String SECOND_JOB_NAME  = "Second Sample Scheduler Job";
    private static final String SECOND_GROUP_NAME   = "Second Sample Scheduler Group";
    private static final String SECOND_TRIGGER_NAME = "Second Sample Scheduler Trigger";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Invoking scheduler for Sample..");
        try {
            String cronExpression = getInitParameter("firstCronExpr");
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();            
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger(FIRST_TRIGGER_NAME, FIRST_GROUP_NAME, cronExpression);
            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(FIRST_JOB_NAME, FIRST_GROUP_NAME, SomeClass.class);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);

            cronExpression = getInitParameter("secondCronExpr");
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(); 
            cronTrigger = new CronTrigger(SECOND_TRIGGER_NAME, SECOND_GROUP_NAME, cronExpression);
            jobDetail = new JobDetail(SECOND_JOB_NAME, SECOND_GROUP_NAME, SomeClass.class);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);

            log.log(Level.INFO, "Sample Timer scheduled...");           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problem invoking SampleSchedulerServlet to schedule the Sample jobs..");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    public String getServletInfo() {
        return null;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        try {
            Scheduler sched = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            sched.shutdown();
            log.log(Level.INFO, "Shutting down Sample scheduler - Successful !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Shutting down Sample scheduler - FAILED !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```